# Conditional Probability of A given B, is it not just A?

Tags: probability, statistics

If Conditional Probably is defined as $P(A\mid B) = \frac{\displaystyle P(A \cap B)}{\displaystyle P(B)}$,

and $P(A \cap B)$ is defined as $P(A) \times P(B)$,

is $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$?

Comment: It seems... ($P(A) \gt 0$).

Comment: I would say - P(A∩B) is defined as P(A)×P(B) only for independent events, not generally.So generally is not P(A/B)=P(A).

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ should not be defined to be $P(A)\cdot P(B)$.  For instance if you roll a fair six-sided die, let event $A$ be roll is even; and event $B$ be roll is odd.

Comment: @georg After some reading I just found that. If you put that as the answer I will accept

Comment: This is not necessary.   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A)P(B)$

For example, if $A$ is the event "when rolling a dice, it comes out 6" and $B$ is the event "it comes out 5" you can see that if you know that B happened (ie a 5 has been rolled) then you know that A has *not* happened

In this case $P(A|B) = 0 \neq P(A) P(B)$

If B does not give you any information about A, then we say that A and B are independent and in this case 
$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ and indeed $P(A|B) = P(A)$

An example would be A = " roll a six " and B = "tomorrow rains"

(This is not a formal explaination, but I believe it does the job of conveying the concept )